# Changing text in a div

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, hide

My aim is once I click on each photo - which are not displaying now( but you can see the broken image icon) text inside this div "core-tab-sec"
should change. You see now three paragraphs and each of them is for one of the photo. So two of them should be hidden and only one displayed.

Can anyone help me with this?
So here is ALL of my code 
https://jsfiddle.net/net1994/7zovyuow/

```
<div class="core-tab-sec">
<ul class="core-tabNav">
<li class="active"><a href="#tab1"><figure><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/people-icon.png" alt="PEOPLE"></figure><div>PEOPLE</div></a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2"><figure><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/passion-icon.png" alt="PASSION"></figure><div>PASSION</div></a></li>
<li><a href="#tab3"><figure><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/performance.png" alt="PERFORMANCE"></figure><div>PERFORMANCE</div></a></li>
</ul>

    <div class="core-tabCnt">
        <div class="core-tabSec" id="tab-1">
        <p>We believe in people. People solve problems. Our employees are passionate problem solvers always looking for long-term solutions that will benefit our clients and OneIMS. They thrive in and promote a collaborative and innovative environment, working hard to achieve corporate goals.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="core-tabSec" id="tab2">
        <p>We could not be a marketing company without being passionate about innovation. From keeping up with industry changes to using the latest techniques, our creativity and passion drives innovation that helps our clients achieve their goals.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="core-tabSec" id="tab3">
        <p>The success of our clients is driven by results. Results are driven by our performance. That’s why we relentlessly pursue success, strive for flawless execution, work hard and continuously look for ways to maximize our client’s return on investment. </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

How to do this?
Can I do with css or js?
Thanks!!

Comment: share the script that you have tried

Comment: you can create two class in css hide and show and add and remove those class in paragraph div according to click on image

Answer (score 0):

for example you wanna show the id = tab2 and remaining is hide 
just use the 
{`$('.core-tabSec').hide();
$('#tab2').show();`

}

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using jquery. On click of image/link bind an even which add/remove classes from your paragraphs

```
$( ".core-tabNav li a" ).click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('show');
});
```

And define class in css to toggle display

```
display: block / display: none
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery. Please check working complete [jsfiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/7zovyuow/9/)

```
     $('.core-tabNav li').each(function(e){
        $(this).find('a').on('click', function(){
        var paragraphID = $(this).attr('href'),
                pragraph = $(paragraphID);

            hideAll();

                pragraph.show('fast');
                        console.log(pragraph);
      });

    });
    function hideAll(){
        $('.core-tabSec').hide();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you so much Kamaal! I gotta learn this now!

Answer (score -1):

Please Check the below code in jQuery. You have to include script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"> for the below code to run properly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").click(function() {
     if($(this).attr('alt') === 'PEOPLE') {
         $('.core-tabSec').hide();
         $('#tab-1').show();
     }
     else if($(this).attr('alt') === 'PASSION') {
         $('.core-tabSec').hide();
         $('#tab2').show();
     }
     else {
         $('.core-tabSec').hide();
         $('#tab3').show();
     }
   });
});
```